# Deprecation of force_uaccess_begin() in Linux kernel 5.19 / 6.0?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I try to rebuild a Linux device driver in recent kernels, namely 5.19 and 6.0.

The functions `force_uaccess_begin()` and `force_uaccess_end()`, as well as type `mm_segment_t`, are no longer defined and the compilation fails.

In the source code of the driver, for kernels before 5.10, the old `set_fs()` was used. For 5.10 and higher, `force_uaccess_begin()` and `force_uaccess_end()` are used instead. Up to kernel 5.14 at least, it compiles. The `force_uaccess_*()` functions are defined in `linux/uaccess.h`.

With kernels 5.19 and 6.0, the compilation fails. The `force_uaccess_*()` functions are no longer defined in `linux/uaccess.h`. I have no intermediate kernel 5.15 to 5.18 to test.

I could not find any precise online information about this. The transition from `set_fs()` to the `force_uaccess_*()` functions is abundantly documented but not the removal of the latter.

As far as I can see from the headers in 5.14 and the evolution of some other drivers, it *seems* that the `force_uaccess_*()` functions are no longer necessary and can be fully removed.

I have two questions:

1. Could you confirm that the `force_uaccess_*()` functions are no longer necessary and calling them can be *safely* removed? Or what shall we care about? I did not write that driver, so that would require some investigation.
2. What is the first kernel version where the `force_uaccess_*()` functions were removed? This is required to write the exact `#elif LINUX_VERSION_CODE ...` in the code.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: removed in 5.18 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.15/A/ident/force_uaccess_begin

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: @Rob, come on, there is one single topic here, a very specific change in the kernel. "How" and "when" are two aspects of the same question. Please learn to make the difference between the spirits of the law and the letter of the law (Montesquieu).

Comment: I guess that `force_uaccess_begin` was **temporary replacement** for the code in the *kernel core* while `set_fs`  functionality was being removed. And in 5.18 they finally have dropped that functionality. [That article](https://lwn.net/Articles/832121/) describes reasoning of such removal.

Comment: It is hard to say that calls to `force_uaccess_*()` can be "*safely* removed". The functions were probably removed when there were no longer any callers in the kernel sources. Linux kernel maintainers don't generally care whether functions were being used by out-of-tree kernel modules or not.

Comment: Follow up to my earlier comment: There is no longer anything for `force_uaccess_begin()` and `force_uaccess_end()` to do in kernel 5.18 onwards since the whole concept of allowing kernel-space addresses to be treated like user-space addresses was removed in 5.18. Therefore, calls to those functions can be safely removed in kernel 5.18 onwards as there is nothing left to replace them.

Comment: @IanAbbott: "Therefore, calls to those functions can be safely removed in kernel 5.18 onwards as there is nothing left to replace them." - Hm, by "can be **safely** removed" I understand that if a correct code calls those functions then one may remove those calls and expect the **code** to **remain correct**. But in the given case, if a code **uses** copy_to_user/copy_from_user for access kernel memory, after removing calls to `force_uaccess_*` the code becomes incorrect, because those kernel memory accesses would fail.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It's the `set_fs(KERNEL_DS);` calls that cannot be safely removed.