# Can force_uaccess_begin() be removed safely in after linux kernel 5.18?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, linux-device-driver

The questions are same as those in [Deprecation of force_uaccess_begin() in Linux kernel 5.19 / 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966928/deprecation-of-force-uaccess-begin-in-linux-kernel-5-19-6-0)
I cannot ask question on that question line because I don't have enough reputations so I created a new question.

1. Could you confirm that the force_uaccess_*() functions are no longer necessary and calling them can be safely removed? Or what shall we care about?
2. What is the first kernel version where the force_uaccess_*() functions were removed? Is it linux version 5.18. Is there any official announcement about this removement?

Comment: "Could you confirm that the force_uaccess_*() functions are no longer necessary and calling them can be safely removed?" - No, you cannot just remove a call to a no-longer-defined function and expect things to work. You need to rewrite your code for not use functionality provided by those functions. The way of rewriting depends on **your code** itself. BTW, this is written in the [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966928/deprecation-of-force-uaccess-begin-in-linux-kernel-5-19-6-0#comment132346317_74966928) to the referenced question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev On further reflection, I believe it is safe to remove these calls for kernel 5.18 onwards, since the functionality they affect no longer exists. I added a [new comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966928/deprecation-of-force-uaccess-begin-in-linux-kernel-5-19-6-0#comment134656550_74966928) to the referenced question.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for your answer. About your description ": There is no longer anything for force_uaccess_begin() and force_uaccess_end() to do in kernel 5.18 onwards since the whole concept of allowing kernel-space addresses to be treated like user-space addresses was removed in 5.18. " , is there any official resource that can refer to?

Comment: @T.Cris There are various mentions in [Changelog-5.18](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.18) about removing the `CONFIG_SET_FS` option for various architectures, and then removing it globally. Removal of `force_uaccess_begin()` and `force_uaccess_end()` is not specifically mentioned in the ChangeLog, but was part of the global removal of the `CONFIG_SET_FS` option (see [commit 967747bbc084](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=967747bbc084b93b54e66f9047d342232314cd25)) since the functions became redundant at that point.

Comment: @IanAbbott I see your comment: It's the set_fs(KERNEL_DS); calls that cannot be safely removed.    So does it mean that if we use set_fs(KERNEL_DS) before, we still need to find a way to replace it?

Comment: @T.Cris The functionality of set_fs(KERNEL_DS) has been removed and there is no safe way to replace it if the code is calling functions in the kernel that expect a user-space address and they are being passed a kernel-space address. If all the code that deals with user-space addresses and kernel space addresses is local to the module's own functions, it can either define different functions for handling user-space and kernel-space pointers, or add some parameters to allow the functions to work out which address space the pointer is addressing. (EDIT: changed "is safe way" to "is no safe way".)

Comment: Thanks for your gret help. There are some replacement suggestions in https://lwn.net/Articles/832121/